# How to add two agents in transport Fleet Block

Tags: addition, agent, transport, fleet

I am wondering that how could I add two agents in the transport fleet. For example in the picture one is AGV and other is My AGV.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO7UR.png)

Thanks

How could we used two agent simultaneously in the model with the help of transport fleet block in free space model?